# When I run this php code it reports an error: Undefined offset

Tags: php, html, file

When I run this php script it reports an error : 'Undefined offset' 
How would I fix this error?

```
 $dir = "....\folder";

$array = scandir($dir);
$hold = 0;
$num = count($array);
(int)$num;
while($hold != $num ){
  echo($array[$num]);
  if (strpos($array[$num], '.txt') !== false) {
    if (time()-filemtime($array[$num]) >1800) {
      echo($array[$num]);
      unlink($array[$num]);
    }
  }
  $hold++; 
}
```

Comment: Probably better to `foreach($array as $file)` and work with `$file`.  And maybe better `foreach(glob("$dir\\*.txt") as $file)` then you only get `.txt` files.

Comment: PHP can be used in forms.